# Magickcore can't set/get a single pixel

Tags: c, imagemagick

I am using MagickCore in imagemagick Q8 and I can't set specific pixel, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <magick/MagickCore.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    Image *imagen;
    ImageInfo *imagen_info;

    ExceptionInfo *exception;
    PixelPacket *q;

    MagickCoreGenesis(*argv,MagickTrue);

    exception=AcquireExceptionInfo();
    imagen_info = AcquireImageInfo();
    (void) CopyMagickString(imagen_info->filename,argv[1],MaxTextExtent);

    ReadImage(imagen_info, exception);

    q = GetAuthenticPixels(imagen,0,0,1,1,exception);

    q->red = 255;
    q->green = 123;
    q->blue = 220;

    SyncAuthenticPixels(imagen,exception);

    /* Write the image then destroy it. */
    WriteImage(imagen_info, imagen);
    DestroyImage(imagen);
    DestroyExceptionInfo(exception);

    MagickCoreTerminus();

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to read an image from a file and then edit a pixel and then save image to disk.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `q = PixelPacket` is not a valid expression (and therefore neither is `q.red = ...`). Look at MagickCore's documentation / Learn C (whatever is more appropiate).

Comment: and that was the only error? check it again please

Comment: If you got errors *you* are supposed to list them. As it is, this fragment is not even an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Hello, i pasted a more comprehensible code, i am trying to read a image from file and edit a pixel and then save it to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example provided, your `imagen` variable remains in a NULL pointer. It should be assigned by the return value of `ReadImage`.

```c
imagen = ReadImage(imagen_info, exception);
```

The only other issue I see would be the assignment of color values on the `PixelPacket`. Assuming your working with RGB, you would need to calculate the Quantum color value.

```c
q->red = 255 * QuantumRange;
q->green = 123 * QuantumRange;
q->blue = 220 * QuantumRange;
```

*Note: this will issue a compiler warning, see [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Color.html) for working with colors*